# set tkinter Optionmenu's title to a string and a StringVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I have an Optionmenu with a title "options" and some options there. The title changes every time I choose something to variable1. How can I set it after it changes,  to a string "options" and to variable's value?
For example: "options - music off" 
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
variable1 = StringVar() 
variable1.set("something",variable1)
```

Thanks.

Edit: Here is a complete version of my code:

```
            options = Menubutton(frame,textvariable = options3,indicatoron=True,borderwidth=1, relief="raised", width=20)
            options.grid(row=3,column=2)#options2 [0] options3
            main_menu = Menu(options,tearoff=False)
            options.configure(menu=main_menu)
            get_options3= options3.get()
            neededstring = string+str(options3)
            print("needed str", neededstring)
            options3.set('options - ' +options3.get())
            for item in (("Answer with text", "plain text", "only numbers", "only letters"),
             ("Answer with Checkbuttons", "red", "green", "blue"), ("Answer with Radiobuttons", "one option can be chosed")
                         ):
                menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=False)
                main_menu.add_cascade(label=item[0], menu=menu)
                for value in item[1:]:
                    menu.add_radiobutton(value=value, label=value, variable=options3)
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't work because the `.set()` method takes only one parameter.  You could try `variable1.set("options - " + variable1.get())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trace the StringVar you give to the OptionMenu, you can add the string onto the front whenever the option is changed. This creates a window with an OptionMenu that does this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# function to add 'options - ' to the front of the selected option
def change_selected(var1):
    var1.set('options - %s' % var1.get())

# variable
var1 = tk.StringVar(root)
var1.set('1')

# create menu
options = tk.OptionMenu(root, var1, '1', '2', '3')
options.pack()

# trace variable for changes
var1.trace('w', lambda *args: change_selected(var1))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it is a bit slow on my computer.